# How can I search for a specific date and month from an array in Excel which also includes the year

Tags: excel, date

So in English, I want to search all the annual arrays to count the number of occurrences of each date (i.e. how many times 11th November occurs in the 2019 array, 2020 array, 2021 array and 2022 array etc.)

=SUMPRODUCT(('2022'!A$2:'2022'!A$38=DATEVALUE(E4)))

This formula works for searching for a date from this year but when I use the same formula for an array which has a different year (to this year) this doesn't work.

Even though I have changed the cell E4 to just be in the format dd/mm that only applies to the appearance of the cell

when clicking on the cell it's still in the form dd/mm/yyyy

All the arrays require me to have the year so it's not a matter of changing those.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Using Functions `Day` and `Month` will create a critera that ignores the year.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Day('2022'!A$2:A$38)=day(E4))*(Month('2022'!A$2:A$38)=month(E4)))
```

Or a simplified version for similar questions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Day(A:A)=19)*(Month(A:A)=11))
```

Also, if you wanted to avoid errors if there is text in your fields, I'd put `N()` function in to turn text to zeros. So:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Day(N('2022'!A$2:A$38))=day(E4))*(Month(N('2022'!A$2:A$38))=month(E4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Random date fact that cost me $50 in a bet.... there's no Feb 29 in the year 2100.

Comment: Keep yor money in you wallet by knowing: If you want to know if a year is a leap year: evenly divisible by 4 -> leap year; UNLESS evenly divisible by 100 -> not a leap year; UNLESS: evenly divisible by 400 -> leap year

Comment: Yea well Microsoft found that too complicated too when it first created excel. Check the value for `=date(1900,2,29)` does exist which it shouldn't. This is why google sheets starts with a date of 12/31/1899 instead of Microsof'ts 1/1/1900.